# Surface area of revolution formula

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, surfaces

Hey so I have looked through other threads, and searched online but I can't find a good explanation as to why the surface area of revolution is 2π$\int y\sqrt{1+\frac{dy}{dx}^2}\ dx$ and not just 2π$\int y dx$

Since for volume of revolution its π$\int y^2 dx$, as its just integrating each area to get the volume with $\pi r^2$, so why can't you just integrate each perimeter to get the surface area to get 2π$\int y dx$?

For context this is the surface area I am trying to find where
$y=x^3$.

[image: graph of y equals x cubed from 0 to 2]

Comment: What is $h$ in your formula? Do you know how to find the surface area of a piece of a cone? That is relevant.

Comment: @TedShifrin Sorry that was a mistake. I have made the necessary changes

Comment: It's because the error in estimating the surface area of a slice of that shape by the surface area of a cylindrical slice is too big. The expression $\sqrt{1+(y')^2}$ accounts for the length of the curve.

Comment: Think about how you use chords to estimate length of a curve, not horizontal line segments. For a surface of revolution, the proper approximation is by frusta of cones, not pieces of cylinders.